Discord.js message_reference[MESSAGE_REFERENCE_UNKNOWN_MESSAGE] Error
i was creating a command in discord.js and i found this message_reference[MESSAGE_REFERENCE_UNKNOWN_MESSAGE] error. i tried solving it using chatgpt. still not able to fix it
node:events:497
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

DiscordAPIError[50035]: Invalid Form Body
message_reference[MESSAGE_REFERENCE_UNKNOWN_MESSAGE]: Unknown message
    at handleErrors (C:\Users\amitd\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\index.js:727:13)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async SequentialHandler.runRequest (C:\Users\amitd\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\index.js:1128:23)
    at async SequentialHandler.queueRequest (C:\Users\amitd\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\index.js:959:14)
    at async _REST.request (C:\Users\amitd\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\index.js:1272:22)
    at async TextChannel.send (C:\Users\amitd\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\interfaces\TextBasedChannel.js:182:15)
Emitted 'error' event on Client instance at:
    at emitUnhandledRejectionOrErr (node:events:402:10)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:84:21) {
  requestBody: {
    files: [],
    json: {
      content: 'Could not find the target voice channel.',
      tts: false,
      nonce: undefined,
      enforce_nonce: false,
      embeds: undefined,
      components: undefined,
      username: undefined,
      avatar_url: undefined,
      allowed_mentions: undefined,
      flags: undefined,
      message_reference: { message_id: '1295933246755966986', fail_if_not_exists: true },
      attachments: undefined,
      sticker_ids: undefined,
      thread_name: undefined,
      applied_tags: undefined,
      poll: undefined
    }
  },
  rawError: {
    message: 'Invalid Form Body',
    code: 50035,
    errors: {
      message_reference: {
        _errors: [
          {
            code: 'MESSAGE_REFERENCE_UNKNOWN_MESSAGE',
            message: 'Unknown message'
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  code: 50035,
  status: 400,
  method: 'POST',
  url: 'https://discord.com/api/v10/channels/1292965991780716605/messages'
}

Node.js v20.16.0`


const channelId = '1293020925058355240'; 

const voiceChannel = message.guild.channels.cache.get(channelId); 

if (!voiceChannel || voiceChannel.type !== 'GUILD_VOICE') {
  return message.reply("Could not find the target voice channel.");
}

// Increment the order counter
orderCounter++;

const newChannelName = `Orders: ${orderCounter}`;

try {
  
  await voiceChannel.setName(newChannelName);
  
  
  await message.channel.send({
    content: `The Order count is updated! It’s now a total of **${orderCounter}** Orders || Updated by <@${message.author.id}>`
  });
} catch (error) {
  // Log the error to the console for debugging
  console.error('Error renaming the voice channel:', error);

  // Send an error message in the text channel
  await message.reply('There was an error renaming the voice channel.');
}


im a beginner in discord.js.

Welcome to the SO community! Are you sure that message exists? Because the error clearly indicates that the message is unknown therefore impossible to reply to an unknown or deleted message

this is my code, it's work for me.
try to check bot access permission from voice channel.
and recheck Intents.
const client = new Client({
  intents: [
    GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildMembers,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages,
    GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent,
  ]
});
let orderCounter = 0;
client.on("messageCreate", async (message) => {
  if (!message.guild) return;
  if(message.member?.user.bot) return console.log('is bot');
  const channelId = "1291782583855874063";

  const voiceChannel = message.guild.channels.cache.get(channelId);

  if (!voiceChannel || voiceChannel.type !== ChannelType.GuildVoice) {
    return message.reply("Could not find the target voice channel.");
  }

  // Increment the order counter
  orderCounter++;

  const newChannelName = `Orders: ${orderCounter}`;

  try {
    await voiceChannel.setName(newChannelName);

    await message.channel.send({
      content: `The Order count is updated! It’s now a total of **${orderCounter}** Orders || Updated by <@${message.author.id}>`,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    // Log the error to the console for debugging
    console.error("Error renaming the voice channel:", error);

    // Send an error message in the text channel
    await message.reply("There was an error renaming the voice channel.");
  }
});

